# Cannot create Controller and View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller

I have Visual Studio 2010 with MVC 2 installed. I am able to create a MVC 2 Web Application and build the project with the original code. However, I cannot create any new Controller or View page to the project. When I try to create a Controller, I got this error:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Item Templates\CSharp\Web\MVC 2\CodeTemplates\AddController\Controller.tt(-1, -1): error: There was a problem getting an AppDomian to run the transformation from the host. The process cannot continue."

When I try to create a View, I get this error:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Item Templates\CSharp\Web\MVC 2\CodeTemplates\AddView\Empty.tt(-1, -1): error: There was a problem getting an AppDomian to run the transformation from the host. The process cannot continue."

I have tried to reinstall the VS and SP1, but that didn't solve the problem.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Consider upgrading to MVC3.

Comment: @SLaks, while I agree with your suggestion, I don't see how this is helpful in the OPs situation who is using MVC 2 currently.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: That's why it's not an answer.

Comment: Do you have the following xml node <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" /> in [Program Files]\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenx.exe.config

Comment: MVC 3 doestn't work either. I got the same error.

Comment: I added <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" /> to devenx.exe.config, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error this morning in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 10 while running through an MVC2 tutorial I found. I restarted and reloaded the solution, it created the view right away.